# C# refer to parent

Tags: c#, oop, parent-child

sorry for my stupidity but I'm looking for a way to construct an object from a class that connects to a service and also contains another class with methods for the service.

The problem I'm facing is trying to figure out a way to only have to connect to the service once. I refuse to use global variables and the likes.

I'm finding it difficult understanding the object concepts in C# as my programming background mainly comes from JavaScript.

Any help is most appreciated.

```
namespace Tests.Classes
{
    public class L
    {
        dynamic uri;
        dynamic service;
        dynamic credentials;
        dynamic proxy;

        public L L()
        {
            this.uri = new Uri("bladie bladie blah");
            this.credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            this.credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            this.proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(this.uri, null, this.credentials, null);
            this.service = (IOrganizationService)this.proxy;
            return this;
        }

        public class OL
        {
            public OL OL(dynamic a)
            {
                this.service = parent.service; // <- doesn't compile
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it clear how it's called:

```
var l = new L();
l.OL("haha");
```

Maybe my code isn't clear enough. This will keep the categorization fanatics at bay :P.

```
namespace Tests.Classes
{
    public class L
    {
        Uri uri;
        IOrganizationService service;
        ClientCredentials credentials;
        OrganizationServiceProxy proxy;

        public L L()
        {
            this.uri = new Uri("hBladie Bladie Blah");
            this.credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            this.credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            this.proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(this.uri, null, this.credentials, null);
            this.service = (IOrganizationService)this.proxy;

            return this;
        }

        public class OL
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            IOrganizationService service = null;

            public OL OL(dynamic a)
            {
                if (a is Entity)
                {
                    this.entity = a;
                }
                if (a is string)
                {
                    this.entity = new Entity(a);
                }

                return this;
            }

            public OL attr(dynamic key, dynamic value)
            {
                this.entity[key] = value;
                return this;
            }

            public Boolean save()
            {
                this.parent.service.create(this.entity); // parent does not exist
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hate messy programming, I love jQuery style.

Here's how the code has to be used:

```
new L().OL("haha").attr("Hello", "world").save();
```

or

```
var l = new L();
l.OL("HAHA").attr("foo", "bar").save();
l.OL("pff").attr("boppa", "deebop").save();
```

Comment: First, replace `dynamic` with `var`. You don't need dynamic.

Comment: It's not clear what you want `parent` to be, or why all your variables are declared using `dynamic`...

Comment: doesn't answer my question but okay

Comment: IMHO you need an introductory text to C#, which is widely out of scope for a question here.

Comment: What do you mean not clear? It's supposed to refer to L.service

Comment: Probably because JavaScript is dynamically-typed (is that what it's called) and C# is strongly-typed (is that what it's called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would have worked in Java. In C#, you need to pass L to OL's constructor:

```
public OL(dynamic O, L parent)
{
   this.service = parent.service;
}
```

By the way, your constructor won't compile, you have two `OL`s there, and a `return`.

By the way 2, why are you using so many dynamics?

Comment: Was pure example.. Dynamics because they always work :D (I come from a JavaScript background where everything is dynamic)

Comment: "because they always work". No, they always compile. Make a typo or some other mistake and they won't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do somethign like this:

```
public class OL
{
    dynamic olService = nnull;
    public OL OL(dynamic a)
    {
          this.olService = parent.service; // <- doesn't compile
          //return this; //remove this !!!!
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

Just note: try to not use `dynamic` untill you really need that. Use strong types in `C#` language as much as it possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single `service` to exist for all instances of your classes, declare it as `static`. e.g.:

```
static IOrganizationService service;
```

Then in your nested class, you can refer to it by `L.service`.

Comment: How can I change its value when it is static?

Comment: @Chris, I mentioned in my answer that you can refer to it by `L.service`. e.g.: `L.service = ...;`